# Cannot find symbol variable gso, Firebase Google authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a problem with adding Google authentication to my project.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        signUpBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uSingUpBtn);


        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso); <<error: cannot find symbol variable so
```

Android Studio cannot find `gso`, I don't know why. Please help, or just let me know what 'gso' means. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because GoogleSignIn's [getClient(Context context, GoogleSignInOptions options)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn#getClient(android.content.Context,%20com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions)) method, as you can see requires a `GoogleSignInOptions` object as the second parameter. So in order to create a `GoogleSignInClient` a `GoogleSignInOptions` object is needed.

To solve this, you can create that object like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

Now, the following line of code will work:

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
```